# How to apply forces to character with gamepad in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I've been following Brackey's tutorial on this, see the excerpt from my code below. In his tutorial it only teaches "transform.Translate", how do I use this gamepad input system tool to add forces to the character to make them move instead? So I can have jump physics, and when they're in space they'll keep the momentum.

```
{
    NewControls controls;

    Vector2 move;
    Vector2 rotate;
    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new NewControls();

        controls.Gameplay.Jump.performed += ctx => Jump();

        controls.Gameplay.Walk.performed += ctx => move = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        controls.Gameplay.Walk.canceled += ctx => move = Vector2.zero;

        controls.Gameplay.Rotate.performed += ctx => rotate = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        controls.Gameplay.Rotate.canceled += ctx => rotate = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 m = new Vector2(move.y, move.x) * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(m, Space.Self);**

        Vector2 r = new Vector2(rotate.y, rotate.x) * 100f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(r, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

To move with rigidbody controls, you have to use things like “forward” or “left” but I want one joystick to control the forward, backwards, and side to side movements. I don’t know how to use the joystick input for moving in all those directions. The tutorials have them as separate arrow keys

does anyone have some sample code, or a tutorial to point me to, or just some explanation?  it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you started by [typing "control character with physics in Unity" into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=control+character+with+physics+unity&ia=web), and found the wealth of tutorials showing how to do this with a [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) or [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) component? What have you tried based on your research so far? Where did you run into a specific obstacle that we can help you overcome?

Comment: The other tutorials are for keyboard controls, and not using the controller package like in this brackeys video   https://youtu.be/p-3S73MaDP8    I don’t know how to have the rigidbody movement without changing the input system

Comment: The input source does not change the Rigidbody methods. These are orthogonal topics. Try editing your question to show how you've tried replacing your Transform code with Rigidbody code, and explain in detail where you're having trouble.

Comment: To move with rigidbody controls, you have to use things like “forward” or “left” but I want one joystick to control the forward, backwards, and side to side movements. I don’t know how to use the joystick input for moving in all those directions. The tutorials have them as separate arrow keys

Comment: Your code already shows how to combine a horizontal and vertical movement into a vector that you can use as a force or a velocity. There is no requirement to use only "forward" or "left" when using Rigidbodies.

Comment: I tried to use  rb.AddForce(move.x, move.y);  but I get errors :/ I'm new to unity so I don't have the intuition of how to combine things into new code. could you please provide an example of a syntax that works with this?

Comment: That looks like a detail that should be part of your question, including the specific error message.

Comment: Thank you! I posted what I found as the solution so anyone with the same problem will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've solved my problem! I used

rb.velocity = new Vector3(move.x, move.y);

instead of

rb.AddForce(move.x, move.y);